# Background pixel in fragment shader

Tags: opengl

There is some method to access the background pixel in a fragment shader in order to change the alpha blending function?

I try to implement the fragment shader from page 5 of [Weighted Blended Order-Independent Transparency](http://jcgt.org/published/0002/02/09/paper-lowres.pdf) but I don't know how to get Ci.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In standard OpenGL, you can't read the current value in the color buffer in your fragment shader. As far as I'm aware, the only place this functionality is available is as an extension in OpenGL ES ([EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch.txt)).

I didn't study the paper you linked, but there are two main options to blend your current rendering with previously rendered content:

### Fixed function blending

If the blending functionality you need is covered by the blending functions/equations supported by OpenGL, this is the easiest and likely most efficient option. You set up the blending with `glBlendFunc()` and `glBlendEquation()` (or there more flexible variations `glBlendFuncSeparate()` and `glBlendEquationSeparate()`), enable blending with `glEnable(GL_BLEND)`, and you're ready to draw.

There are also extensions that enable more variations, like [KHR_blend_equation_advanced](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/KHR/blend_equation_advanced.txt). Of course, like with all extensions, you can't count on them being supported on all platforms.

### Multiple Passes

If you really do need programmable control over the blending, you can always do that with more rendering passes.

Say you render two passes that need to be blended together, and want the result in framebuffer C. The conventional sequence would be:

```
set current framebuffer to C
render pass 1
set up and enable blending
render pass 2
```

Now if this is not enough, you can render pass 1 and pass 2 into separate framebuffers, and then combine them:

```
set current framebuffer to A
render pass 1
set current framebuffer to B
render pass 2
set current framebuffer to C
bind color buffers from framebuffer A and B as textures
draw screen size quad, and sample/combine A and B in fragment shader
```

A and B in this sequence are FBOs with texture attachments. So you end up with the result of each rendering pass in a texture. You can then bind both of the textures for a final pass, sample them both in your fragment shader, and combine the colors in a fully programmable fashion to produce the final output.